# Filling an empty vector

Tags: r

Here's a super newbie question.  I'm working through The Art of R Programming and came across this simple code:

```
z <- NULL 
for (i in 1:10) if (i %% 2 == 0) z <- c(z,i)
z
```

the output is `c(2,4,6,8,10)`.

What I don't understand is why you need `c(z,i)` to populate the vector `z`.  Why wouldn't `c(i)` work.  When I do that, it skips straight to the last iteration and fills vector `z` with the last associated value.  Is there some form of rule that governs populating vectors?  Try as I might, I didn't find a clear answer anywhere, just a bunch of samples that, while they made sense, didn't help me solve the above.

Comment: use print to see what the loop is doing, it is not skipping to the last iteration

Comment: it's just joining each `i`  that is TRUE for the `if` statement to all the previous ones that were also TRUE

Comment: It depends on your desired output. If you just put `z <- c(i)`, whenever that assignment line is reached (i.e., whenever `i` is even), `z` will be overwritten with the current value of `i`. If what you want is `2 * (1:5)`, you need to append `z` with the new value each time.

Comment: Also FWIW this strikes me as a silly exercise -- a poor use of `for` loops and poor practices as regards declaring `z` of 0 length and then appending.